# connect telnet with python

Tags: python, sockets, telnet, telnetlib

I tried to connect bbs with python's library "telnetlib", try to make a robot to answer

the message. While I answered the message,the robot return more than 1 message.These are my

code.

```
# -*- coding: cp950 -*-
import telnetlib,random
#f= open("ans.txt","r")
ans = [b"oao", b"xd"]
'''while True:
line = f.readline()
if line = "":
    break
ans.append(line)
'''

tn = telnetlib.Telnet("ptt.cc")
tn.read_very_eager()
tn.write(b"*****\r\n")  # this is where i enter my username
tn.read_very_eager()
tn.write(b"*****\r\n")  # this is wher i enter my password
tn.read_very_eager()
tn.write(b"\r\n")

while True:
if tn.read_very_eager() != "" :
    tn.write(b"")
    tn.read_very_eager()
    tn.write(b"su\r\n")
    tn.read_very_eager()
    tn.write(b"\r\n")
    tn.read_very_eager()
    tn.write(b"\r\n\r\n←")
    tn.read_very_eager()
    tn.read_very_eager()
    for i in range(0,1000000):
        x = 1
```

Comment: Could you explain what 'message' means here? What was expected and what you got?

Comment: Counting to one million ? import time
time.sleep(1.0)

Comment: Please provide the very_eager function too. Without that, debugging is almost impossible.

Comment: Excuse me,but read_very_eager is the standard function.

Answer (score 0):

First, I have absolutely no experience with telnet.

Looking at the [Python documentation on telnetlib](http://docs.python.org/library/telnetlib.html#telnet-example) I can see some differences between your code and the example at the bottom of the docs page.  The major difference is they wait for a prompt to log-in or provide a password.  Even if your `read_very_eager` *should* do the same thing, it's more clear to `read_until`.  It could solve your problem, or give you a hint about it.

Try adapting the example to fit your needs.

```
import sys
import telnetlib

HOST = 'ptt.cc'
user = 'username'
password = 'pass123'

tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST)

tn.read_until("login: ")
tn.write(user + "\n")
if password:
    tn.read_until("Password: ")
    tn.write(password + "\n")

# Do anything you need to here.
# If your server will accept these, try them first to isolate the problem
tn.write("ls\n")
tn.write("exit\n")

print tn.read_all()
```

As mentioned by MatthieuW, you could sleep with the time library.

```
from time import sleep

print 'Start'
sleep(1)
print 'One second later'
```